# how can I overcome an element or elements for not applying the conditions of loop or skip an element using python?

Tags: python, list

> currently I have list(s) of a company's pricings as

```
quote_2021=['100000-200000','10000-100000','5-1000','0','50-1000','10,000','50000-60000']
```

> Earlier I was using the following to get the desired answer but its breaking as conditions are not satisfied of have elements divided with'-' as now we have single amount as well like '500000' or '0'

```
quote_2020=['200000-210000','760000-900000','25-3000','50-2000']
output = [f'{int(x.split("-")[0]):,}-{int(x.split("-")[1]):,}' for x in quote_2020]
quote_2020
```

> As now we have single values as well in list like '0' or '1000' so I tried putting an if statement
> using loop where I added "-0" in end of elements like '1000-0' before applying previous code but its
> affecting the result as its making no sense of'1000-0'
>
> Any suggestions will be really helpful if I am able to set the logic to get result like this

```
quote_2021=['100,000-200,000','10,000-100,000','5-1,000','0','50-1,000','10,000']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing everything in one line, you can create `if/else` statements for different conditions. Here is the way to do it:

```
quote_2021=['100000-200000','10000-100000','5-1000','0','50-1000','10,000','50000-60000']

clean_quotes = []
for each_quote in quote_2021:
    # Check if there is '-' in string
    if '-' in each_quote:
        clean_quotes.append(f'{int(each_quote.split("-")[0]):,}-{int(each_quote.split("-")[1]):,}')
    else:
        # check whether number has its own comma or not
        if ',' in each_quote:
            # if yes, we assume comma is in correct place
            clean_quotes.append(each_quote)
        else:
            #  else add comma
            clean_quotes.append(f'{int(each_quote):,}')
```

`clean_quotes` will look like this:

```
['100,000-200,000', '10,000-100,000', '5-1,000', '0', '50-1,000', '10,000', '50,000-60,000']
```

Comment: Great Man, Actually I rarely used "in" in "If-else" so I was really confused about it. Thank You so much for this idea, from now I will also try to use this method more often , I wish you a great day ahead ;)